# R mapply two lists element wise

Tags: r, list, apply

I have 2 lists. One list provides the indices as follows:

```
dd[1:3]
[[1]]
[1]  2  5  6  7  9 14 16

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
integer(0)
```

The second list contains strings as:

```
ee[1:3]
[[1]]
 [1] "HP"     "A"   "HP"     "HP"    
 [5] "BD"  "A"   "A"   "NY"
 [9] "U"          "HP"     "HP"     "HP"    
[13] "HP"     "S"        "HP"     ""       
[17] "0"            

[[2]]
[1] "HP"  "HP"  "HP"  "HP"  "T"
[6] "HP"  "HP"  "0"         

[[3]]
[1] "HP" "HP" "0"
```

I want to apply the indices from the list dd to the corresponding elements of `ee`, e.g. select 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 14, 16 elements from `ee[[1]][1]` and then compute the length of unique elements. I want to do it in a vectorized fashion as the lists are huge.

I know this is a simple application of `mapply`, and that I am missing something obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Data

```
dd <- list(c(2,  5,  6,  7,  9, 14, 16), 5, integer(0))
ee <- list(c("HP", "A", "HP", "HP", "BD", "A", "A", "NY", "U", "HP", 
             "HP", "HP", "HP", "S", "HP", "", "0"),
           c("HP", "HP", "HP", "HP", "T", "HP", "HP", "0"), c("HP", "HP", "0"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about `Map`. Actually, I also want to compute the `length` of `unique` elements obtained. Now, I can do a separate `lapply` with `length` and `unique` on the output obtained by `Map` but is there a way to do it in conjunction with `Map` as that will be faster?

Comment: you need to mention that in your question

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in this way using mapply:

```
mapply(function(x,y){
     table(x[y])
  },ee,dd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to loop over the sequence of one `list` using `lapply`, subset based on the index of another and get the frequency of the elements

```
lapply(seq_along(ee), function(i) table(ee[[i]][dd[[i]]]))
```